# Bluetooth LE can't send data from central to peripheral

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am dealing with BluetoothLow Energy problem. I find my peripheral BLE device with iPhone, connect to it, also find service and the characteristic which is in write mode. But when I try to send some data, nothing happens - device doesn't receive anything and also `- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error` is not called.

My writeValue method is here:

```
-(void) writeValue:(int)serviceUUID characteristicUUID:(int)characteristicUUID p:(CBPeripheral *)p data:(NSData *)data {

    CBUUID *UUIDService = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]];
    CBUUID *UUIDCharacteristic = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]];

    NSLog(@"ALERT");
    CBService *service = [self findServiceFromUUID:UUIDService p:p];
    if (!service)
        {
            NSLog(@"Could not find service with UUID %@ on peripheral with UUID %@",
                  [self CBUUIDToString:UUIDService],
                  p.identifier.UUIDString);

            return;
        }

    CBCharacteristic *characteristic = [self findCharacteristicFromUUID:UUIDCharacteristic service:service];
    if (!characteristic)
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not find characteristic with UUID %@ on service with UUID %@ on peripheral with UUID %@",
              [self CBUUIDToString: UUIDCharacteristic],
              [self CBUUIDToString:UUIDService],
              p.identifier.UUIDString);

        return;
    }

    NSString *message = @"AB";
    NSData *dataMsg= [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [p writeValue:dataMsg forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` called? What does `findCharacteristicFromUUID:`?

Comment: Nope, `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error: ` is NOT called either.  `findCharacteristicFromUUID: ` simply checks if UUID which I wrote is the same as one of the service's characteristics: ` -(CBCharacteristic *) findCharacteristicFromUUID:(CBUUID *)UUID service:(CBService*)service
{
    for(int i=0; i < service.characteristics.count; i++)
    {
        CBCharacteristic *c = [service.characteristics objectAtIndex:i];
        
        if ([self compareCBUUID:c.UUID UUID2:UUID]) return c;
    }
    
    return nil; //Characteristic not found on this service
} `

Comment: What logs `characteristic` when you found it?

Comment: <CBCharacteristic: 0x14d5f280, UUID = 00035B03-58E6-07DD-021A-08123A0003FF, properties = 0x8, value = (null), notifying = NO>

Comment: Its property is "write". Tried it from other iOS app which communicated through this characteristic. My code just ignores that line and I don't get my written value in peripheral side.

Comment: `findCharacteristicFromUUID:` is CBCharacteristic method and in my situation gives out the right characteristic. Thank you that you help me, maybe you have some other opinion about the problem? :/

Comment: @Larme Do you have any idea? Still stuck.. I would really appreciate any help..

Comment: What if you keep reference of your characteristic instead?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will try this, but not sure about changes. What about pairing process?  In BLE Utility app  sending some data automatically forces pairing. How could my app do that too and then successfully transfer data?

Comment: Pairing is called itself when a characteristic has a special property (flag encryption needed or something like that). When you try to read it or write on it, it should trigger something. But that's another topic. Question: Did you enter in `didDiscoverCharacteristic` ?

Comment: Ok, thank you for helping! But maybe that is the fault in my problem - in BLE Utility app peripheral side forces pairing and Central side then connects and only then data is sent. Do I need some implementation in my Central app to somehow deal with that pairing attempt (now just nothing happens)? EDIT: I enter `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:`. Needed Char is found

Answer (score 0):

Try to this. swift 3
This code for enable notify for CBCharacteristic(0x12 for notify property).

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    for newChar: CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics!{

        peripheral.readValue(for: newChar)

        if newChar.properties.rawValue == 0x12{

            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: newChar)
        }
    }
}
```